# Como hacer esta lista por compresión de una lista anidada en Python

Tags: python-3.7

Llevo un rato y no hay manera de hacer este código usando las listas por compresión. Por favor, es pura curiosidad, me está matando....

```py
listaPalabras = ['gato','perro','conejo']
listaLetras = [ ]
for unaPalabra in listaPalabras:
    for unaLetra in unaPalabra:
        if unaLetra not in listaLetras:
            listaLetras.append(unaLetra)
        else:
            pass
print(listaLetras)
```

No se pueden repetir las letras. Tengo también la duda de si entendí
la pregunta bien porque, sólo pide que no se muestren copias e igual
se podría convertir a conjunto???

*Como un desafío adicional, intente averiguar cómo eliminar las duplicaciones*

Comment: `list(set("".join(listaPalabras)))`. Mira mamá, sin bucles ni comprensiones! :-)

Comment: Que buena, si Señor. Gracias
He notado un poco de sarcasmo con un pobre estudiante???? Es coña, gracias.

Comment: Naa, nada de sarcasmo. Sólo intentaba bromear con la expresión "mira mamá, sin manos" (famosas últimas palabras). Ahora en serio, el truco es convertir toda la lista a una sola cadena, usando `"".join()` para concatenarlo, y aprovecharse de que la cadena es en sí un objeto iterable, por lo que se le puede pasar a `set()` para que itere sobre ella y construya el conjunto de los caracteres. Al final paso el resultado a lista por si es eso lo que necesitabas.